# Remove last selected element from the multiple select if user select more than 3 option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select

I need to select only 3 options from the multiple select. If user selects more than 3 options than the last selected element should be replaced by the new one clicked.

I have a example as follows:

```
<select multiple id='testbox'>
      <option value='1'>First Option</option>
      <option value='2'>Second Option</option>
      <option value='3'>Third Option</option>
      <option value='4'>Fourth Option</option>
      <option value='5'>Fifth Option</option>
      <option value='6'>Sixth Option</option>
      <option value='7'>Seventh Option</option>
      <option value='8'>Eighth Option</option>
      <option value='9'>Ninth Option</option>
      <option value='10'>Tenth Option</option>
    </select>
```

When user selects

```
First option
Second option
Third option
```

Now he reaches max selection limit 3 .If he click on the another option like **Tenth Option** I need to remove **Third option** and get selected **Tenth option**

For that i tried this but no idea how I can achieve my goal

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1");

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //alert("1111");
      var last_valid_selection = null;

      $('#testbox').change(function(event) {
        if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
          alert('You can only choose 2!');
          $(this).val(last_valid_selection);
        } else {
          last_valid_selection = $(this).val();
          latest_value = $("option:selected:last",this).val()
          alert(latest_value);
        }
      });

    });
    </script>
```

Please suggest some idea or solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var lastOpt;
$('#testbox option').click(function () {
    lastOpt = $(this).index();
});
$('#testbox').change(function () {
    if ($('option:selected', this).length > 3) {
        $(' option:eq(' + lastOpt + ')', this).removeAttr('selected');
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/BMA4A/)

Answer (score 6):

This works quite nicely:

```
var lastSelected;

$("#testbox").change(function() {
    var countSelected = $(this).find("option:selected").length;

    if (countSelected > 3) {
        $(this).find("option[value='" + lastSelected + "']").removeAttr("selected");
    }
});

$("#testbox option").click(function() {
    lastSelected = this.value;
});
```

I had to set a global variable `lastSelected` as well as an options click event to capture the actual last option clicked (`this.value` in the change event was giving me the top selected option, not the actual last option).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JAysB/1/

Comment: This doesn't work if the order of the selections is not numerically sequential. For instance, select "Eighth, Ninth, Second, First" or "Third, Seventh, First, Eighth".

Comment: I just thought OP wanted the option that was below the fourth selected to become unselected.

Comment: If I read it correctly, he wants the fourth selection to replace the third selection, no matter the numerical value.

Comment: @DevlshOne -- Easy fix, give me a minute :D

Comment: Actually, might be a bit harder than I thought, `this.value` is grabbing the earliest selected option, not the current clicked...hmm

Comment: What if two options have the same value? :) I've developed mine to be a bit more goof-proof.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I don't like jQuery, so I've developed the same ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpTT8/1/)), but in pure, vanilla, easy-to-read JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('testbox').selopt=new Array();
document.getElementById('testbox').onchange=function(){
    for(i=0; i<this.childNodes.length; i++)
        if(this.childNodes[i].tagName!='OPTION')
            continue;
        else{
            if(this.childNodes[i].selected &&
               this.selopt.indexOf(this.childNodes[i])<0)
                this.selopt.push(this.childNodes[i]);
        }
    if(this.selopt.length==4)
        this.selopt.splice(2,1)[0].selected=false;
}
```

P. S. No global variables! :P

Comment: And, FYI, it may be easilly modified to deselect not the last selected, but the least selected element: `selopt.splice(2,1)[0].selected=false;` -> `selopt.splice(0,1)[0].selected=false;`.

Comment: Love this solution, +1 for the Pure JS :D